# AWS Amplify upload to s3 using iOS framework incredibly slow

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have an iOS amplify app.  I'm trying to upload images to my bucket using the following code:

```
let dataString = "My Data"
let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)!
let storageOperation = Amplify.Storage.uploadData(key: "ExampleKey", data: data)
let progressSink = storageOperation.progressPublisher.sink { progress in print("Progress: \(progress)") }
let resultSink = storageOperation.resultPublisher.sink {
    if case let .failure(storageError) = $0 {
        print("Failed: \(storageError.errorDescription). \(storageError.recoverySuggestion)")
    }
}
receiveValue: { data in
    print("Completed: \(data)")
}
```

With a stable fast wifi connection, the average upload time for files that are about 300kb is 30 seconds.

This is unacceptably slow.  Is there anyway to improve upload speeds here?

Comment: I see the same on an Android app. But there is a huge variation between different ISP.

Comment: If there is a way to pass the image or file base64 data with the api request it can be inserted in the table using on dynamodb lambda trigger.  But I haven’t found a way to pass the data in the api mutation request without that data being inserted into the dynamodb table.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I haven't figured this out.  I think there is an issue with the callback on S3 uploads if your region is far displaced.  I have US region and uploading from Asia.  The upload is very fast but the callback takes about 15 seconds.  Seems the problem not so bad from US region.  I really don't know if this is the issue or something else.  I only know that the upload times for S3 are comically ridiculous.  Up to 30 seconds for 200KB with a high speed connection.

Comment: A workaround is to add Rest API to your application as well as any other api you already have and upload images to S3 using a lambda.  But it's a lot of unnecessary overhead for a problem that shouldn't exist.